# Cannot use test-kitchen with lxc

Tags: debian, chef-infra, lxc, test-kitchen

I am trying to setup my test-kitchen setup with lxc. Lxc is working fine on my machine and i have tested it. 
When i try to do `kitchen create` i am getting following error.

```
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.6.0)
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ClientError
>>>>>> Message: Could not load the 'lxc' driver from the load path. Please ensure that your driver is installed as a gem or included in your Gemfile if using Bundler.
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

My `.kitche.yml` file is

```
---
driver:
  name: lxc

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: test-container
    driver_config:
      username: ubuntu
      password: ubuntu

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
    attributes:
```

This is what i did to setup things.

1. Install chefdk.
2. Go to a dir and run `kitchen init --driver=kitchen-lxc --create-gemfile`
3. Run `kitchen create`

Also my test-container lxc was present at this point of time.

==> I have also run `chef gem install kitchen-lxc` as mentioned in one of answers.

I have no idea why this error is coming. Any pointer in right direction will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the `kitchen-lxc` driver library. If you've install this all via ChefDK (which you should): `chef gem install kitchen-lxc`.

That said, I'm not sure how up-to-date the `kitchen-lxc` driver is. You might want to check out `kitchen-docker` instead.

Comment: I have install kitchen-lxc and still getting same error.

Comment: Make sure you install it into the same Ruby environment that `kitchen` is using. Unfortunately debugging this via comments is probably impractical. The easiest solution is to make sure you're using the version installed via ChefDK and remove any other copies of test kitchen.

Comment: I am testing this on a newly installed machine. It has only chefdk installed apart from basic system utilities.

Comment: How did you install `kitchen-lxc`?

Comment: as coderanger said, make sure you install lxc driver using `chef gem install kitchen-lxc`

Comment: @coderanger I have edited my question. Please check.

Comment: You probably don't mean to be using a Gemfile or interacting with Bundler at all. Please remove the Gemfile and try again.

Comment: It is still failing. Also do i need to provide some image path or something like that. I have seen on internet that box_url is given. Do i also need to provide something like that in lxc?